# Reliable messaging over TCP in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm starting a school project in node.js. It's a system that consists of couple of node.js servers connected via TCP sockets.

I tried some TCP libraries (Net module from node itself, nssocket from nodejitsu, now i'm experimenting with zeromq) but they don't seem to have one important feature: message delivery confirmation.

What I would like to have is some kind of library that allows to do something like this:

```
client.connect(server, port);
client.send(data, function callback(err, res) { ... });
```

The callback function would be called after the message is delivered or when something bad (timeout, network failure) happens during sending.

I was thinking I would write my own protocol over TCP but I would prefer somethink more robust and tested.

Thanks for any constructive answers :)

Comment: I think you'd have to send something back saying "yep, I got it" to be sure. Even when it reaches the final physical destination, what about buffering etc? Plus this is TCP, there's no such thing as a "message". It's a stream.

Comment: yep, I thought of something like this. but now what should I do when the "yep, i got it" packet is lost? Buffering is not really an issue (I think) - I use the nssocket library that deals with it (or I could simply write some wrapper that adds delimiters to the data...).  What I was looking for was some kind of library that provides an "message abstraction" over TCP and assures me whether the message is either delivered or lost... This requirement is absolutely crucial for me (and I don't think it is that exotic :) I' almost sure other people must have dealt with it as well...)

Comment: Err, there's no such thing as a "lost packet" in TCP, or indeed such a thing as a "packet". It's a stream, and the delivery and order of the bytes in that stream is _guaranteed_ (unless the socket closes or whatever, obviously). What _isn't_ guaranteed is whether the data will be fragmented or lumped together.

Comment: ok, i should probably take a deeper look at TCP. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really convenient, because what happens when you `A->B` goes fine, but the receive confirmation fails (`B->A`)? Anyhow, it's pretty easy to roll your own, something like (pseudo):

**Sender**

```
var callbacks = {};
function send (msg, callback) {
    // assign unique request id
    msg.msgId = uuid.v4();
    msg.timestamp = new Date();
    callbacks[msg.msgId] = callback;

    // send over TCP
}

socket.on("confirmation", function (msg) {
    callbacks[msg.msgId](null);
    delete callbacks[msg.msgId];
});

// now you'll need some polling mechanism that checks for messages that take
// more than the timeout and clean them
```

**Receiver**

```
socket.on("message", function (msg) {
    // send confirmation to sender
    socket.emit("confirmation", { msgId: msg.msgId });
});
```